# AngularJS number format filter directive for input using NgModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I would like to create a directive for an input control that formats a number with X number of decimal places when the input doesnt have focus.  When the input does have focus, i would like the number to appear unformatted (no commas).

I am almost there, with the following code.  When you click inside the input, the text changes and when you click out (blur event) the text formats again.  However, if i change the value in the input, then the events seem to change round, and the blur event does nothing. Then if you click in the input box again, the value formats when it shouldnt, and the blur event unformats, when it should format.

To use the directive you can simply do

```
<input number-format ng-model="myValue" decimals="numberOfDecimals" />
```

Here is the directive

```
App.directive('numberFormat', ['$filter', '$parse', function ($filter, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            var decimals = $parse(attrs.decimals)(scope);

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from view format to model format
                return $filter('number')(data, decimals); //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from model format to view format
                return $filter('number')(data, decimals); //converted
            });

            element.bind('focus', function () {
                element.val(ngModelController.$modelValue);
            });

            element.bind('blur', function () {
                element.val(ngModelController.$viewValue);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: With the way you've defined `$parsers`, the directive will store formatted numbers to the model (i.e. if you entered `123456`, `$modelValue` will be set as `123,456`, which ends up being a string) every time you edit the associated input field. Instead of using `$parsers` and `$formatters`, why not consider a `$watch()` on the model value instead?

Comment: I am not sure adding a watcher is the best idea. I don't like the thought of an extra watcher for each instance of the directive. I could have maybe 50 of these on screen. 50 extra watchers doesn't sound good. Must be able to do this without a watcher.

Comment: Well, if you insist, here's a minor change that should do the trick. You don't say anything about model validation so I assume you're OK with managing that, http://plnkr.co/edit/wSflQs9bXYvihL5jUrvc?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the change, i figured the $parser change had to use parseFloat, but not the blur change so thanks.  But now you have me worried, with the comment "You dont say anything about model validation..."  Well i would like to  use ng-required on this so i am guessing thats fine?

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. By validation, I was referring to how you deal with users putting in silly values into the input field. I updated my Plunker with a crude example of what you might want to do (http://plnkr.co/edit/wSflQs9bXYvihL5jUrvc?p=preview). You can then make use the style class `ng-invalid` or check `ngModelController.$invalid`.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you want to add it as answer? I can +1 it for you then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discussion in the question comments appeared to have helped the OP.

`$parsers` was causing user-specified input values to be stored to the model value as the filter number format. For example, if `123456` was entered, the underlying model value would be set to `123,456`. The point here is that the model value should be storing the raw user input, not the user input after formatting is applied. A simple implementation to parse the user input for `$parsers` would be to use `parseFloat()`, like so:

```
ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
    return parseFloat(data);
});
```

To be safe, this parsing function should be improved to accommodate for bad user input. I've provided a rudimentary example of this in my demonstration Plunker.

On blur, the value in the input field should be set to the filtered version of the model value.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/wSflQs9bXYvihL5jUrvc?p=preview)